# Screen freeze, need to relaunch to make clickable screen in swift

Tags: iphone, swift

KapilElevens[552:83280] [Touch] unexpected nil window in __sendSystemGestureLatentClientUpdate, _windowServerHitTestWindow: ; layer = >, touch: phase: Stationary tap count: 1 force: 0.000 window: (null) view: (null) location in window: {0, 0} previous location in window: {0, 0} location in view: {0, 0} previous location in view: {0, 0}

Comment: So what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Some time screen get freeze and when i tap anywhere above error i got, than when i relaunch app then it's work fine.
And every time after login same problem happen and than i need to relaunch app

Comment: I am using below code after login for Dashboard screen
    


      let storybrd = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
      let tabController = storybrd.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dashTab")
      let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabController)
      navController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
      self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue , and problem was one of my podfile which i was using for ActivityIndicatorView. If you are using same try once to remove it